# Unable to load dump file in collabnet subversion server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, collabnet

I want to load a Visual svn dump file to collabnet svn(Linux Cent OS), for this I copied that dump file to different location in server and used

```
svnadmin load /path/repos/test/ < /home/test/test.dump
```

But I don't know why it is throwing this error:

`"<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1 svnadmin: File already exists: filesystem '/path/repos/test/db', transaction '4-4', path 'branches' * adding path : branches ..."[root@test-vmo1 TEST]`

Answer (score 0):

Paths in the dump you attempt to load have duplicates in the target repository, why don't you load it to a clean repository?. You can try loading the dump in another root directory. For example:

```
svnadmin load /path/repos/test/  –parent-dir TEST2 < /home/test/test.dump
```

You should create TEST2 folder before running the command.